# Customize request and response of order REST API

Tags: magento2.3, orders, rest-api, customapi

Guest order placement request -

```
URL - V1/guest-carts/:cartId/order 
Body - {
"paymentMethod":
{
    "method":"testpayment_gateway",
    "customField":"CustomFieldValue" // **This is not product attribute, Payment Gateway dynamic params which is only configured from frontend**
    "addition_data":{
        "test" : "test123"
      },
    }
}}
```

Currently this api shares only order id after successful response

But we need to customize as

```
    {
      "order_id" : "5",
      "transaction_id": "577657"
   }
```

Comment: you have to create custom api for your requirement.

Comment: I agree with Jinesh, create a custom API.

Comment: @jitesh  What is better way 1) Creating new API 2) Write Plugin to manipulate request and response.?